# Will pd.series do sorting of the dictionary keys?

Tags: pandas, series

I am using Jupyter notebook as provide by Jake Vaderplas, " Python Data Science Handbook", and its says : data can be a dictionary, in which index defaults to the sorted dictionary keys

But when I run the code, the output is not sorted for dictionary keys. What m I missing here?

In :

```
pd.Series({2:'a', 1:'b', 3:'c'})
```

Out :

```
2    a
1    b
3    c
dtype :object
```

## While the expected output should be

In :

```
pd.Series({2:'a', 1:'b', 3:'c'})
```

Out :

```
1    b
2    a
3    c
dtype :object
```

Comment: I guess this should be possible in some old version of pandas, now it not sorting.

Comment: I think the sentence is trying to say "sorted as the dictionary keys are sorted". If the author meant sorted as in alphabetically, the sentence would not make sense, for two reasons: Dictionaries do not sort per se, and the way it is worded, implies that the dictionary keys would already be sort. 'sorted dictionary keys' means dictionary keys that are already sorted, not to be sorted. If the author meant for them to be alphabetically sorted, he might say, 'index defaults to dictionary keys sorted alphabetically.' Hope that helps.

Comment: In Oreilly's book "Python for Data Analysis" section 5.1 Series it is written that "When you are only passing a dict, the index in the resulting Series will have the dict’s keys in sorted order."  But I doubt if it is correct! I think @jezrael is correct this behavior removed in new versions

Comment: Yes, in this book, the version of Pandas was sorting keys by default when the Series was built from a dictionary. This is visible in examples with slicing of string keys, today the slicing returns all keys in the original order of the dictionary, not keys within the alphanumerical interval as shown in the book.

Answer (score 3):

First to make you clear, pandas series are not `sorted` by default. But if you want to make a series which should be `sorted` by index,

```
sr = pd.Series({2:'a', 1:'b', 3:'c'}).sort_index()
sr
```

Output:

```
1    b
2    a
3    c
```

This will give you required result.

Answer (score 2):

Add `.sort_index()` to your code and you will get the result as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Python for Data Analysis - Second Edition, in Page 125, we can see the author provided the text and example given below.
***"When you are only passing a dict, the index in the resulting Series will have the dict’s keys in sorted order"***

During Dictionary creation, you can see the city names not in order. However the result shows is in order.

```
sdata = {'Ohio': 35000, 'Texas': 71000, 'Oregon': 16000, 'Utah': 5000}

obj3 = pd.Series(sdata)
obj3

# Ohio 35000
# Oregon 16000
# Texas 71000
# Utah 5000
# dtype: int64
```

I assume the reason could be the changes induced in dictionary object.

Comment: In a newer versions of Pandas it doesn't sort (I guess)